# UnetSocket send() returns a Nonetype object

Tags: python, sockets, groovy, send, unetstack

I am trying out the python code specified in the UnetStack Handbook. While running **tx.py** and **rx.py**, UnetSocket object is created successfully as I print it out on the terminal, but the send() function sends Nonetype data at the receiver.

**tx.py** ===>>

```
from unetpy import UnetSocket

s = UnetSocket('localhost',1101)
print(s)
s.send('hellooo',31)
s.close()
```

---

**rx.py** =====>>>

```
from unetpy import UnetSocket
s = UnetSocket('localhost',1102)
rx = s.receive()
print('here ',rx)
print('from node : ',bytearray(rx.data).decode())
s.close()
```

First I run 2-node-network.groovy on the Simulator.
Then rx.py and next tx.py from the terminal.

**Error at rx.py**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rx.py", line 6, in

```
print('from node : ',bytearray(rx.data).decode())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

**O/p at tx.py**
<unetpy.UnetSocket object at 0x7fe2909d4550>

Comment: A pull request has been raised to fix the issue: https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/pull/51

You should be able to use it with latest version shortly.

Comment: @Sayali: You can also use [this](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/issues/49) `rx.py` example just for now.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to reproduce your problem with the latest versions of unetpy + fjagepy.  Seems to be a bug introduced in 1.7.1 release of fjagepy (I am assuming you have version 1.7.1 installed). Try:

```
pip install fjagepy==1.7.0
```

and then repeat your test to see if it works.

P.S. I have reported the problem to the maintainer for fjågepy and so hopefully we should have a fix in the next release. Until then you can use 1.7.0 release, if that works for you.

Comment: Is this resolved now?  I noticed the pinned version in fjagepy was updated to 1.7.2 last week in the unet-contrib repo.